# How to print a simple table to the console using a loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to create a table that looks like this:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

I was able to get it done by doing this:

```
for x in range(0, 50, 10):
    print(x, x + 1, x + 2, x + 3, x + 4, x + 5, x + 6, x + 7, x + 8, x + 9)
```

But it seems like this definitely isn't the most efficient way to do it. I've tried adding:

```
    # for y in range(1, 10):
        # print(x, x + y)
```

after the first for loop in my original code, but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: For future reference, "it doesn't work" is not a valid description of a problem - see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have a range of options - e.g. (1) use `" ".join(...)` on the list of numbers in each row, or (2) `print` with the argument `end=" "` to avoid creating a new line for every number.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for letting me know!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/3767239).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop and join a list comprehension for each row to print your table.

```
for i in range(0, 50, 10):
    print(' '.join([str(j) for j in range(i, i + 10)]))
```

Similarly, you can unpack a row as a list into the print method's parameters.

```
for i in range(0, 50, 10):
    print(*[j for j in range(i, i + 10)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `end` parameter of the `print()` function:

```
for x in range(50):
    if (x+1)%10 == 0:
        end_char = "\n"
    else:
        end_char = " "
    print(x,end=end_char)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

The `print()` function add a new line at the end of each statement by default, but you can modify how the string should end: `"\n"` (new line) if the next number is divisible for `10`, `" "` (a space) otherwise